# Dymola diagram view in Simulation tab

Tags: dymola

In Dymola 2020/2021 I use the **Diagram** view in the **Simulation** tab to analyse simulation results. However, sometimes I accidentally close the **Diagram** view.

On the ribbon it is possible create new plot views, new tables and new animations, but no new *diagram*. How can that be done?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Re-opening the "Model View"/Diagram in the simulation ribbon is possible using the buttons in the status bar at the very bottom of the Dymola UI. On the very right of it you will find the "legacy" icons for views. Clicking the Dymola-Icon (marked by a red circle below) will show the "Model View".

[image: Dymola GUI, opening of Model View in Simulation Ribbon]